# Url Routing directories in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I want to have a route for a folders and directories. I want for example this:

> {Controller}/{action}/{folder}

when the controller is "Home", the action is "Files", every thing after the action I will consider it as a folder. Like this:

> /home/files/BigFolder/ChildFolder/AnotherChildFolder/File.txt

How can I write that route? So that it routes to the Files action?

Thanks!

**Update**: if I put an * like this `/{*folder}`, it works. But only if I write as folders example:
/Home/Files/Folder/ChildFolder/

But if I put a file it does not work, like this:

```
/Home/Files/Folder/ChildFolder/text.txt
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array format of the route definitions:

```
{Controller}/{action}/{*folder}
```

Comment: great thanks! It works! I did not know that. But if i put a file like: Files/Folder/file.txt . It gives me an error. There is any way to handle the file like a string, routing to the files action?

Comment: You can always write your own routing handler, but I'm sure you can do it with normal routing strings as well. I'm not sure what you mean though, your example is missing the controller name isn't it?

Comment: I have updated my question... yes I mean: /Controller/Action/Folder/file.txt

Comment: Oh I see, it's the extension that's throwing it off. Do you by any chance have IIS 7 or 7.5? If so this might be of use: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368

Comment: That's the best I got then sorry, you could try writing your own routing handler, maybe you'll have better luck.